# Creating a Partial Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, forms

I am having problem with creating a partial scroll bar and `span` focus.

This is my code on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mf8Lf5ea/):

Firstly, I want to make a scrollbar for the form, Secondly I want the `span` (right in front of the `label`) to turn white when I click on the `input`.

Comment: so you want to make the scroll like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mf8Lf5ea/1/ and when click on input the yellow labelled numbers on the left turn to white?

Comment: exactly sir. more detail, i want my scrollbar thumb has a rounded shape, and scroll trail is a line with 2 or 3px.

Comment: to customize scrollbars you'll have to use jQuery plugins, you can use like nicescroll

Comment: i applied this snippet    
`$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("html").niceScroll({cursorwidth: '10px', autohidemode: false, zindex: 999 });
});` but it doesnt works :(

Comment: Make sure you added jQuery library? If yes then check in console what error it's showing..

Comment: i did it. thank you sir :D